# github api v3 to fetch contents of a file from a particular branch other than master

Tags: github

How to use github  v3  contents api to fetch a file's contents from a particular branch
http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/
 i tried these options
https://api.github.com/repos/'org_name'/'repo_name'/contents/'file_path'
https://api.github.com/repos/'org_name'/'repo_name'/contents/'file_path'/?ref=branch_name
or quite a few options , but it fetches the file contents from the masters branch only.

but i need to fetch the contents from a branch other than master.
I know i am missing something very basic , but not a figure out what.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's strange because it seems to work for me. Here is the URL for fetching the index.html file in the gh-pages branch from the tracing-framework repo from Google's GitHub organization:

https://api.github.com/repos/google/tracing-framework/contents/index.html?ref=gh-pages

The index.html file doesn't exist in master.

Can you give the exact URL you are trying?

Comment: thanks Ivan .. ref param works perfectly, it was that someone deleted that branch remotely , so the local branch with that name was present , but remote one was missing and i kept thinking that i am not using the api correct way.thanks this works https://api.github.com/repos/google/tracing-framework/contents/index.html?ref=gh-pages  perfectly

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on a Mac that comes across this and can't figure out why they're seeing the following response to their cURL (like me):

> zsh: no matches found:

You need to escape the '?' so it looks more like:

[https://api.github.com/repos/google/tracing-framework/contents/index.html\?ref=gh-pages](https://api.github.com/repos/google/tracing-framework/contents/index.html%5C?ref=gh-pages)

Comment: It worked, thank you. And it is very annoying to find out..